# MVC inject DataAccessLayer based on the logged in user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've an application which insert/save data in different databases hosted on different server. UI may be different but at the end data which is getting saved is almost same.
So i want to use the same DataAccessLayer but want to change the connectionString based on the loggedin user. 
Dependency can be configured in startup.cs but at that time i may not know the DataBase user would like to work with.

on login page i'm asking user to select the database to work with, so only way to change the connection string is after login page.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?  What issues did you encounter?  It's quite a broad question, but to give a broad answer: have a search for multitenancy in ASP.NET MVC.  Here's a free book with some good information: https://www.syncfusion.com/resources/techportal/details/ebooks/aspnetmultitenant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public class ConnectionRepository : IConnectionRepository
{
    private IDbConnection _cnn = null;

    public IDbConnection GetOpenConnection(string databaseName)
    {
        if (_cnn != null && _cnn.ConnectionString.ToLower().Contains(databaseName.ToLower()))
        {
            _cnn.Open();
            return _cnn;
        }

        var cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString();

        //Now replace database name in connection string with whichever one supplied
        var cb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(cnn) { InitialCatalog = databaseName };

        // wrap the connection with a profiling connection that tracks timings 
        return new ProfiledDbConnection(new SqlConnection(cb.ConnectionString), MiniProfiler.Current);
    }
}
```

This code replaces the InitialCatalog (database name) part of the connection string dynamically base on the supplied name. The current name is stored in session when the user logs in.

Hope this helps.